# How to get everything after the set string using xslt 2.0 tokenize or any similar function

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have the following snippet and I would like to use it to grab everything except the first group of characters that are essentially numbers ranging from 1 to 4 digits. The groups of characters are separated by space. I have tried few ways with tokenize without success. I am able to either get the second, third or fourth item one at a time but not everything at once.

Here is my source file:

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <!-- This is my first comment -->
     <ol>
        <li>1 data</li>
        <li>2 data</li>
        <li>3 data</li>
        <li>4 data</li>
        <li>5 data additional data</li>
        <li>6 data</li>
        <li>7 data</li>
        <li>8 data</li>
        <li>9 data</li>
        <li>1055 data</li>
        <li>1100 data</li>
        <li>1247 data</li>
        <li>1345 data more data</li>
     </ol>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is my snipped:

```
<xsl:template match="li">
    <document>
        <title>
            <xsl:variable name="test" select="text()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($test, ' ')[2]"/>

        </title>
        <doc:id>
                <xsl:number value="substring-before(., ' ')"/>
            </doc:id>

    </document>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
 <title>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ' ')"/>
 </title>
```

Comment: @ManOU, The substring-after is fine but if you want to use `tokenize` you simply need `<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., ' ')[position() gt 1]"/>`.